# Find intersection by 2 vectors on the globe

Tags: android, geolocation, latitude-longitude, intersection

I am trying to calculate intersection GPS coordinate by 2 vectors.
Vector#1 is created by (longitude#1, latitude#1) and (longitude#2, latitude#2).
Vector#2 is created by (longitude#3, latitude#3) and (longitude#4, latitude#4).

My main point is finding intersection by above 2 vectors. I've tried to calculate intersection on X,Y/longitude, latitude/ coordinate system. But it was not accurate location.

Can you help you for my issue ?

```
findIntersection(double long1, double lati1, double long2, double lati2, double long3, double lati3, double long4, double lati4) {
     //...find intersection.
     return intersectionLong, intersectionLati;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See this website: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

There is a section called **Intersection of two paths given start points and bearings** which is what you want.